# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Eheh, whoops. Trying out some new tools for starting elections and the timing seems to be off. This was meant to come out in about 3 hours rather than right now, but, well, let's onwards with this then I s'pose!

Comment: @GraceNote that explains why I was able to read the announcement and now get a blank page.

Comment: @Steve The original setting accidentally set the election times all at 0:00 UTC rather than 20:00 UTC. We shuffled the timings and... well, since a bit uncharted here, hopefully no extra announcements come up from this. But yes as a result we've pushed the actual nomination phase down a bit.

Comment: @Steve so the "Upcoming Events" link [2015 Community Moderator Election](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) on the main RPi SE is a red-link ATM because the relevant page does not yet (?) exist - the fact that the SE then responds to say "Community Moderator Elections" - "There are no active community moderator elections at the moment." is just something to confuse the users...!